# `tinyfd_selectFolderDialogW()` doesn't work from C# app

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dllimport, openfiledialog

I have a cross-platform C# (.NET) application that uses a "tinyfiledialogs" library.

`tinyfd_openFileDialogW()` (and `tinyfd_openFileDialog()`) works as expected, but `tinyfd_selectFolderDialogW()` doesn't:

1. The dialog doesn't allow me to actually select a folder - the "OK" button is deactivated.
2. It sometimes doesn't open at all - the application freezes.

Here's the code:

```cs
[DllImport("tinyfiledialogs", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr tinyfd_selectFolderDialogW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string aTitle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string aDefaultPath = "");

...

outFolderPath = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(tinyfd_selectFolderDialogW("Выберите папку для установки"));
```

I have tried to use `tinyfd_openFileDialogW()` with a "Select a folder." **(hence the dot)** default file name (so it accepts the folder), but this also requires to set `ValidateNames` to `false`, which is not possible here.

Comment: I've just added the modification you proposed bellow to the C# file offered with [tinyfiledialogs](http://tinyfiledialogs.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to fix it!

The fix is the `[STAThread]` attribute for the `Main()` method:

```cs
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

After I've added it, it worked as expected.

**Updated:** the author just added this to the C# example code, and also there is now the `selectFolderDialog()` method - [tinyfiledialogsTest.cs diff](https://sourceforge.net/p/tinyfiledialogs/code/ci/d9b00572b07e45298bd9f715850b78f88af4d283/tree/dll_cs_lua_fortran_pascal/tinyfiledialogsTest.cs?diff=524f8871a94aca0a341dc67ae5b0efb904e09462)